# Updating Access Database with VB 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

This code does not throw an error but does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

I am a VB6 programmer migrating to .Net

Other code I have is working to add and delete records, not update them...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="

    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                Chr(34) & sAppData & "\Data.mdb" & Chr(34) & _
                ";Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1"
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "update Data set ([1], [2], [3], [4]) values (?, ?, ?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("1", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("2", CType(txtDesc.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("3", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
    Dim cbState As String = ""

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        cbState = "1"
    Else
        cbState = "0"
    End If

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("4", CType(cbState, String)))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that through your `Me.Close()` in the try-catch block, the form is closing before all resources have been cleanly released.

I would do the following:

- `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows updated. Check that this is greater than 0.
- If the number of rows updated is > 0, then only then call `Me.Close()` -- outside of the try/catch block

Finally, I would replace lines such as this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("1", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
```

with the more convenient

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", TextBox2.Text)
```

The AddWithValue() function is especially useful when you're passing localizable things like dates and times.